# Localized App Name in Xcode is not shown properly on device

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I support 22 languaiges for my app and have in infoPlist.strings file set the

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "App Name";
CFBundleName = "App Name";
```

apart from that in plist of the project Application has localized display name flag is als oset to YES.

My problem is that on the first run it is working as expected.If i recomplise without deleting the app from device, the app name turns to name of the target in xcode.

Am i missing anything?

UPDATE : I realized that on the third run bundledisplay name is also shown correctly however.the target name is comming from ${PRODUCT_NAME}.If i set a static value to bundle name it shows it every second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try clean the project (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) and to delete the app from the device?